MAC mini M2, python torch before I upgraded (2.03), used all CPUs using CPUs, but after upgrading to the latest version it only uses 3 cores?
MAC Mini M2 CPU,OS 13.6.6, torch before I upgraded (2.0.3), the same Python program, using CPU calculations, can use all the CPUs, but after upgrading to the latest version 2.3.0 it only works with 2 cores?
Why? What can I do? Thank you! The pictures are screenshots before the 2.3.0 upgrade. My torch uses two processes for GPU and CPU calculations. No multiprocessing software such as multiprocessing is used, the source code is as follows:
class ModelV1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,LL1,LL2,LL3):
        super(ModelV1, self).__init__()
        # 定义多层神经网络
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(LL1, LL2)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(LL2, LL3)
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(LL3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))  # 第一层
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))  # 第二层
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5)
        out = torch.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return out

enter image description here
Already used in python:
torch.set_num_threads(CPU-1) # set pytorch parallel threads number
Doesn't work.
Already conda update all, currently the CPU can be used 260% or less than 3 cores, before it was 680-690%, thanks!

conda create -n torch python=3.10
conda activate torch
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch
According to chatGPT-4o tips, after creating a new environment, the CPU utilization can be more than 90%, however, the actual calculation speed is still slower than 50% of the old environment.
